# Socket time out with IPN

Tags: sockets, paypal, timeout, paypal-ipn

Let me start by saying I am not really a developer. I pieced the below code together a few years ago and while it worked up until last week I don't really understand it. Starting last week every time I get a paypal IPN i get a 110 Connection timed out socket error!

If I got to the page directly in the browser I get the following

Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to ssl://www.paypal.com:443 (Connection timed out) in paypal_ipn.php5 on line 37

Below is the code in my paypal_ipn.php5 any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php     
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); 
$email = $_GET['ipn_email']; 
$header = ""; 
$emailtext = ""; 
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc'))
{
   $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
}
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)  
{
   if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1)
   {
      $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
   }
   else
   {
      $value = urlencode($value);
   }

   $req .= "&$key=$value";
}


// Post back to PayPal to validate new http 1.1
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .="Host: www.paypal.com\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n"; 
$header .="Connection: closer\n\r\n";


$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);     


if (!$fp)
{   
  mail("save10percent.net@gmail.com", "socket error!", "socket error!",    "$errno $errstr"); 
}

else
{ 

 fputs ($fp, $header . $req);


 while(!feof($fp))  
 {

    $res = fgets ($fp, 1024); 


    if(stristr($res, 'VERIFIED') !== FALSE)
    {
        //good payment process transaction
        //code removed to make my post smaller
    }  

    elseif(stristr($res, 'INVALID') !== FALSE)
    {       
        // If 'INVALID', send an email.             
        mail("save10percent.net@gmail.com", "Live-INVALID IPN", "Invalid    \n\n\n res = $res \n\n\n req= $req",$error_email);          
    }       
  }     
} 

fclose ($fp);   

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This socket error is trying to inform you that PayPal does not recognize your SSL certificate as valid and therefore will not open a socket for you.

It appears from this snippet that you are set up for 1024 encryption which is no longer supported.  The requirement starting on February 29th that all SSL certificates MUST be SHA-256 capable (2048). This means that your current SHA-128 certificate is no longer valid for use on PayPal's systems.  If you don't administer your web server you'll want to contact whomever does to upgrade your certificate to one that is supported by PayPal.

https://devblog.paypal.com/upcoming-security-changes-notice/#ssl

Comment: Thanks so much. After I talk to my webhosting company to get the new certificate do I need to update my code at all?

Comment: On line 52 you'll need to change 1024 to 2048 when you have your new SSL certificate in place. Also, it is possible that you have a SHA-2 certificate but your code is only encoding in 1024. You might try simply changing line 52 and seeing if that solves the problem:                                     
EDIT $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);   TO READ: $res  fgets ($fp, 2048);

Comment: Looking at your code, it appears to check the validity of your certificate first before executing the rest of the code; therefore, I doubt that just changing that line alone will fix the problem because that will not be executed until your certificate is validated by PayPal.  Still, you'll want to change that line to make it work again after your certificate is upgraded.

Comment: I tried changing it to 2048 and it didn't work. I'll contact my hosting company about the SSL cert. Thanks so much for your help.